# SQL Select result with FREETEXT / returning row with more occurences

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, ssms

I have the following search term for SQL Server:

*I want to buy a Samsung cell phone and the model should be Galaxy S9*

Table:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | samsung s8 |
| 2 | celular s9 |
| 3 | samsung galaxy s9 |
| 4 | galasxy s10 |

I would like the select to return the ID 3 because it has more occurrences.

Comment: You may want to consider full text earch.

Comment: I used Freetext, but it returns all of the rows, i want the return to be the row with more occurences.
```
select * from Table where FREETEXT(Text,'I want to buy a samsung celphone and the model should be galaxy s9')

Comment: What does "SQL Select result with mo" mean?

Comment: `CONTAINSTABLE()` with the last parameter `1` maybe?

Comment: I'm going to search about the CONTAINSTABLE(), thanks! And about the title, i just updated it, just realised that it was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this at the *word* level is:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from string_split(t.text, ' ') s1 cross join
           string_split(@sentence, ' ') s2
           on s1.value = s2.value
     ) ss
order by ss.cnt desc;
```

Notes:

- This only looks for exact word matches in the two phrases.
- This requires that words are separated by spaces, both in `text` and in "the sentence".
- Duplicate words might through the count off.  This can be managed (say by using `count(distinct s1.value) as cnt`) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of way two select item. For example:

```
SELECT 'I want to buy a ' + A.BrandName + ' cellphone and the model should be ' + A.ModelName 
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT, 1, LEN('sumsung')) AS BrandName
        , SUBSTRING(TEXT, LEN(SUBSTRING(TEXT, 1, LEN('sumsung')))+1, LEN(TEXT)) AS ModelName
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE TEXT LIKE N'%samsung%' AND TEXT LIKE N' %galaxy s9%'
) AS A
```

Comment: I want the select query to be like a sentence and the return should be the row with more occurencies. That sentence "I want to buy a samsung celphone and the model should be galaxy s9." is just an example.

Comment: I updated my answer. check it and give me response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but i wanted something more generical, that sentence was just an example.

My situation is that i want to build a chatbot, and i want this select to return the best answer, that contains more occurences of the question from the user.

Comment: thanks, i just replied! Really apreciate your help, cheers!